# Cast Text to Varchar mysql

Tags: mysql

i need to convert a text type to varchar so here is what i did :

```
INSERT INTO phpfox.phpfox_photo_album_info(album_id, description)
SELECT id, CAST(description as varchar(255)) FROM crea8social.photo_album
```

Its give me this sql error :

```
SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'varchar(255)) FROM crea8social.photo_albums' at line 2
```

If i replace the `CAST(description as varchar(255))` with `"test"` its work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CAST To CHAR. VARCHAR is not supported see:

```
SELECT CAST("1234567890" as char(5));
```

**sample**

```
MariaDB [test]>   SELECT CAST("1234567890" as char(5));
+-------------------------------+
| CAST("1234567890" as char(5)) |
+-------------------------------+
| 12345                         |
+-------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]>
```

see manual_ https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/convert/

Answer (score 2):

Is 255 characters the max length of text that you'd want to receive?
Probably you could look at `SUBSTRING()` function. In this case, the query would look like:

```
SELECT id, SUBSTRING(description, 1, 255) AS test FROM crea8social.photo_album
```

Answer (score 0):

select convert(text_column,  character)